# Exhaustively, how does Java determine your classpath?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I am aware that the following all sometimes impact your classpath, but I would like to know more precisely, when and how do the following impact it?

- `Class-Path` in your manifest
- `CLASSPATH` in your enviornment
- `-cp`/`-classpath` on the command line
- `-jar` on the command line

Example:

I know that if `-jar` is specified that the jar you specify will be on the classpath and that `-cp`/`-classpath`, and `CLASSPATH` will all be ignored.

I believe that if `-cp`/`-classpath` is specified, `CLASSPATH` will be ignored.

`Class-Path` is a near total mystery to me right now. I know that if you specify a jar with `-jar`, it will use the `Class-Path` from that jar's manifest. Will it also use the `Class-Path` of a jar for classes within that jar, even if it wasn't specified by `-jar`? Will it be used for all classes, not just classes within the jar? Do they add together or replace each other? What prescience does `Class-Path` take within your `classpath`? Will it be the last thing checked, the first thing checked, or somewhere in between?

Also, for all the different ways you can specify things to be on your classpath, what is the proper syntax? Are commands valid/required? Can I have multiple `Class-Path`s specified in a manifest (IE, can I put one per line to make it easier to read?)

Answer (score 2):

From the following site http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Environment_Variables.html under *how classes are found*

User classes search path (in short, class path): determined in the following order:

1. Defaulted to the current working directory (.).
2. Entries in the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, which overrides the default.
3. Entries in the `-cp` (or `-classpath`) command-line option, which overrides the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.
4. The runtime command-line option `-jar`, which override all the above.

The user class paths are kept in Java System property `java.class.path`.

Comment: Good start. How do `Class-Path` entries in jar manifests fit into all of this?

Comment: Class-Path entries in JAR files (if referenced from either the `CLASSPATH` env variable or the `-classpath` or the `-jar` option) are _added_ to the class search path. That enables an interesting transitive behavior, where you only start with one JAR file which references some more JARs that in turn reference even more.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose - Say I have `a.jar` and `b.jar` on my `CLASSPATH`. `a.jar` has a manifest with a `Class-Path` mentioning `c.jar`. Are the classes within `c.jar` visible to the classes within `b.jar`? Does it depend on the order things were in on my `CLASSPATH` in the beginning?